# Why the dictionary gets populated inside of this while-loop, but it is "empty" outside of the loop?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary, automation

I am trying to automate file management with Python by collecting the input from the user about the folder's name and the extension that he/she wants to place automatically inside of that folder.

After creating a dictionary to save the name of the folder as a string (dictionary key) and extensions as list of strings, the user populates each list and them I combine both of them when populating the dictionary.

**The Problem:** *I am able to populate the dictionary inside of the loop with the information aforementioned, but I already tried to print the dictionary outside of the while-loop and it doesn't work. Therefore, my program doesn't work for not having the values inside of the dictionary. **Could you please check why I am not able to retain the information inside of the dictionary after getting out of the while-loop?***

**Simulation:** The program works until the last part of the loop (see the picture bellow), after that it closes the window and nothing happens.

[image]

*First part of the code:*

```
import os

# Library that helps to find path of the items
from pathlib import Path

# Create list variables
namefiles = []
nameextension1 = []
flag = True
uanswer = ""
count = 0
count2 = 1
flag2 = True
extbreak = ""

# Create dictionaries to organize the folders
Subdirectories = {}

# This is the while-loop to collect the input from the user and populate the lists/dictionary:*

# Collecting input from the users
while flag:
    flag2 = True
    uanswer = input("\nWould you like to create a Folder in the Library?\n Please, type 'Y' for 'yes'\n or 'N' for 'no':  ")
    if uanswer == "N":
        flag = False
    elif uanswer == "Y":
        namefiles.append(input("\nType in the name of the folder:  "))
        while flag2:
            nameextension1.append(input("\nType in the name of the extension.\n EX: .pdf:  "))
            extbreak = input("\nWould you like to add another extension?\n Please, type 'Y' for 'yes'\n or 'N' for 'no':  ")
            if extbreak == "N":
                flag2 = False
    else:
        print("\nPlease try again!!!")
    # Populating the dictionary
    Subdirectories[namefiles[count]] = nameextension1
    print (Subdirectories)
    count += 1
    # Cleaning the lists to use for the next extension
    nameextension1 = []

# I don't know if this is relevant, but the following step after the while-loop is this:*

file_formats = {file_format: directory
                for directory, file_formats in Subdirectories.items()
                for file_format in file_formats}
```

Thank you for the support & I am sorry if my explanation is not so clear. 
Please, feel free to comment if you have any questions and I will provide as much details as I can :)

***PS:*** Happy mother's day!

Comment: ' it doesn't work ' is rather vague, please tell us exactly what goes wrong - what output do you get exactly?

Comment: Sorry, I just uploaded an image related to the problem. The program works until that part, which is the last part of the while-loop (if uanswer == "N":), then it closes and nothing happens, when I create the dictionary within the code everything works and the files get organized. Hopefully now it is easier to understand what I meant. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just added a break after `flag = Flase`:

```
import os

# Library that helps to find path of the items
from pathlib import Path

# Create list variables
namefiles = []
nameextension1 = []
flag = True
uanswer = ""
count = 0
count2 = 1
flag2 = True
extbreak = ""

# Create dictionaries to organize the folders
Subdirectories = {}

# This is the while-loop to collect the input from the user and populate the lists/dictionary:*

# Collecting input from the users
while flag:
    flag2 = True
    uanswer = input("\nWould you like to create a Folder in the Library?\n Please, type 'Y' for 'yes'\n or 'N' for 'no':  ")
    if uanswer == "N":
        flag = False
        break
    elif uanswer == "Y":
        namefiles.append(input("\nType in the name of the folder:  "))
        while flag2:
            nameextension1.append(input("\nType in the name of the extension.\n EX: .pdf:  "))
            extbreak = input("\nWould you like to add another extension?\n Please, type 'Y' for 'yes'\n or 'N' for 'no':  ")
            if extbreak == "N":
                flag2 = False
    else:
        print("\nPlease try again!!!")
    # Populating the dictionary
    Subdirectories[namefiles[count]] = nameextension1
    print (Subdirectories)
    count += 1
    # Cleaning the lists to use for the next extension
    nameextension1 = []

# I don't know if this is relevant, but the following step after the while-loop is this:*

file_formats = {file_format: directory
                for directory, file_formats in Subdirectories.items()
                for file_format in file_formats}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code was giving `IndexError` when user decides to finish the process. I just replaced the `flag`s with

```
while True:
    ...
    if something:
        break
```

and it works fine.

```
import os

# Library that helps to find path of the items
from pathlib import Path

# Create list variables
namefiles = []
nameextension1 = []
flag = True
uanswer = ""
count = 0
count2 = 1
flag2 = True
extbreak = ""

# Create dictionaries to organize the folders
Subdirectories = {}

# This is the while-loop to collect the input from the user and populate the lists/dictionary:*

# Collecting input from the users
while True:
    uanswer = input("\nWould you like to create a Folder in the Library?\n Please, type 'Y' for 'yes'\n or 'N' for 'no':  ")
    if uanswer == "N":
        break
    elif uanswer == "Y":
        namefiles.append(input("\nType in the name of the folder:  "))
        while True:
            nameextension1.append(input("\nType in the name of the extension.\n EX: .pdf:  "))
            extbreak = input("\nWould you like to add another extension?\n Please, type 'Y' for 'yes'\n or 'N' for 'no':  ")
            if extbreak == "N":
                break
    else:
        print("\nPlease try again!!!")
    # Populating the dictionary
    Subdirectories[namefiles[count]] = nameextension1
    print (Subdirectories)
    count += 1
    # Cleaning the lists to use for the next extension
    nameextension1 = []

print("*"*50)
print(Subdirectories)
```

Comment: You are welcome :) Just a small note: By looking at the screenshot you provided, I think you are executing the code by double clicking. So it closes immediately when an error occurs. I recommend you running your codes from command line so that you can read what did go wrong.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I will definitely do that next time! ;) Have a great day!